# Does the Git client for Windows 10 install an SSH client automatically?

Tags: git, ssh, git-bash, mingw-w64

The question is already in the title.

Following software is meant with Git client:

https://git-scm.com/

I though it comes with:
https://www.openssh.com/

But that is now already on Windows 10 itself.

So now I got the Git Bash installed (based on mingw-w64) and can use `ssh`-commands, where does it come from?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't tell for sure on your system but `which ssh` tells me that it's using the one that comes with git, in my case.

Comment: Yep it tells me this:
$ which ssh
/usr/bin/ssh
So is it the native one of Windows 10?
And actually you brought the answer already, since there seems to come ssh with git, right?

Comment: @Altherius can you tell me the path that you get after `which ssh`?

Comment: Correct, this one came with git.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Git for Windows installs its own SSH client.  It ships a version of OpenSSH with the package.  If you're seeing `/usr/bin/ssh` when you run `command -v ssh`, then you're using the version from Git for Windows.

For many things, it's also possible to use the Windows version, but that version is [known to be broken in some ways](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1470).  For example, it does not work with Git LFS, since it does not handle having `/dev/null` for some of its streams, whereas the Git for Windows and Unix versions support that just fine.  So unless you're certain that you need to use the Windows version for some reason, you should prefer the Git for Windows version.

Comment: Git for Windows now prompts whether to install its own binaries or use the windows OpenSSH client. I wouldn't recommend the windows OpenSSH client, it's garbage